# http proxy heroku login enotfound: getaddrinfoo enotfound api.heroku.com:443

Tags: http, heroku, authentication, proxy

I have just installed heroku and I am using powershell to login but i keep getting this message:

```
enotfound: getaddrinfoo enotfound api.heroku.com api.heroku.com:443
```

any idea?

Comment: Are you behind a company proxy?

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU yes, I think this is the problem.

Comment: i tryied to add :

` set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber
or
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber
heroku login`

But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to solution provided in

[heroku issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44973465/8264275)