# using an http proxy to heroku login

Tags: http, heroku, authentication, https, proxy

I am trying to run heroku login from my work using the

```
> set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber
or
> set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber
> heroku login
```

but for some reason I keep getting the same errors. Can someone please help me?!

`enotfound: getaddrinfoo enotfound api.heroku.com api.heroku.com:443`

I had a problem installing django but I fixed it using -- proxy http://proxy.server.com:portnumber

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try updating the Heroku CLI and, be sure you update to v3 as soon as possible to ensure consistent operation!

Also install apt-transport-https package